# RazorPage with image as base64 doesnt render image

Tags: c#, .net

I have a email service with razorpage engine, that i need to add some images as base64 but for some reason its not working. The base64 works fine on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dwvm2bce/ , but wont show up in the email, what im missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <style type="text/css">
        .mrv-logo {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
        }
    </style>
<html>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<head>
    <img  width="90" height="26" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />

    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mention Razor Pages and email.  Clearly this is a non-standard use case.  You will need to provide many more details about how this project is set up, what packages & technologies you are using, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your image is placed inside the `<HEAD>` portion of your web page. For your image - and all other content to be visible on your page, you have to put it in the `<BODY>` section.

I would read up on HTML and how it is structured here

[W3C HTML Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

The `<img/>` tag is placed under `<head>` and this is an illegal usage.

Place the `<img/>` into the `<body>` tag and try again, and if isn’t enough, save the mail as HTML and watch the generated code with a text editor.

PS: also the `<meta/>` tag is illegal out of `<head/>`, same for `<style>`.
I strongly suggest you a deeper HTML tag learning.